# Add common spelling errors to job tags

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

So I just saw the following job posting:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/125277/lead-software-engineer-android-rovercom?med=clc&ref=small-sidebar-blue-nearyou

I noticed that it was tagged [andriod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andriod)

I wonder how many fewer views this job posting got because of such tag. Maybe we could have a way to suggest tag edits to job posting? Or add lots of spelling error fixes?

Comment: Well, the poster has no one to blame but themselves if no one applies...

Comment: Suggesting edits would be much better than adding lots of common misspellings. (Example: I'd also like to fix Your -> You're in that job ad.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the tag has been fixed in the meantime.

In any case, the current way to go about these issues is to instead flag the listing:

[image: Where to flag a job listing]